# why my own template_name doesn't show instead of default template_name in django?

Tags: django

I need to show my own template_name for (passwordResetConfirm) when I use template_name here I get the default Django template also when I get the successful message from (PasswordResetComplete) I get from the same place I mean (the default Django template too).
however, I get no errors of code.
so, How can I get my own template_name in this case?

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
LoginView,
logout,
PasswordResetView,
PasswordResetDoneView,
PasswordResetConfirmView,
PasswordResetCompleteView,
    )
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# django\contrib\admin\templates\registration\password_reset_done.html

app_name = 'account'


class PasswordReset(PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'account/password_reset_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('account:password_reset_done')
    email_template_name = 'account/reset_password_email.html'


class PasswordResetDone(PasswordResetDoneView):
    template_name = 'account/password_reset_done.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('account:password_reset_complete')


class PasswordResetConfirm(PasswordResetConfirmView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('account:password_reset_complete')
    template_name = 'account/password_reset_confirm.html'

    def func(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name)


class PasswordResetComplete(PasswordResetCompleteView):
    template_name = 'account/password_reset_complete.html'

urlpatterns = [
    # /account/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="home"),
    # /account/login/
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html'), name='login_page'),
    # /account/logout/
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name': 'account/logout.html'}, name='logout'),
    # /account/register/
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    # /account/profile/
    url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    # /account/profile/edit/
    url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    # /account/change-password/
    url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    # /account/password-reset/
    url(r'^password-reset/$', PasswordReset.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    # /account/password-reset/done/
    url(r'^password-reset/done/$', PasswordResetDone.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    # /account/password-reset/confirm/
    url(r'^password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', PasswordResetConfirm.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    # /account/password-reset/complete/
    url(r'^password-reset/complete/$', PasswordResetComplete.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Edit the login src url redirect
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'account:view_profile'
# Edit the login src url redirect in PasswordResetCompleteView
LOGIN_URL = 'account:login_page'
# To activating PasswordResetConfirmView
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

- this image explains the files that I have [files image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XecT.png)
- this image shows password_reset page[password reset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuvMo.png) it work's

Comment: are you talking about page title?

Comment: No, I'm talking about template_name of PasswordResetConfirm and PasswordResetComplete..
when I define the template_name that I need to show my page doesn't show. but instead, show the default page in Django.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, upon trying out different things, this is what worked

```
url(r'password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='password_reset.html', email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',                                                                  subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html', success_url='/password_reset_done/', from_email='your@email.com')),
```

```
    url(r'password_reset_done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html')),
```

```
    url(r'password_reset_confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html', success_url='registration/password_reset_complete.html'))
```

I didnot create custom classes, like you did.

Comment: yes, this path is a default path from Django itself what about if I want to get my own path? I'm really looking for this issue a lot and all the answers the same as you.
but when I work like the tutorial I following it's what I need to do. so, I don't know what is the difference between us? I mean me and tutorial both

Comment: I did create custom classes just to be URL path clear and readable more. the tutorial that I follow actually does what you tell me to do but it's too difficult when I try to read this whole path

Comment: So does that mean the code I showed up,doesn't work for you? Where exactly you stuck?

Comment: no, I don't mean that. I mean i need to use my URL path for (confirm and complete) template as I did create before in (reset and resetDone view) you can see above what I did before.I don't want to run the default template path of Django. the template in (reset and resetDone) has already run and show unlike what happened in (confirm and complete template)  which is viewed in default Django, not my own template